# Opening Windows Form In a Word Add-in

Tags: c#

Hello everyone so I created a simple windows form that is a User Control. On my add in's start up I want to call that user control. When I run the application all it does is open a Word Application, without loading the form's information which is supposed to be like a side pane.

Here is what I have so far.

```
namespace WordAddIn2
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        SidePane sP;
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            sP = new SidePane();
            sP.Show();
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            sP.Hide();
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is the Sidepane form:

```
namespace WordAddIn2
{
    public partial class SidePane : UserControl
    {
        public SidePane()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", "-p");
        }
    }
}
```

If someone could help me identify my simple error, that would be wonderful.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `SidePane` but I use this which creates a `CustomTaskPane` that you can then set the width, visible, etc: `Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(<instance of UC>, "<arbitrary name/title>");`

Comment: SidePane is just the name of my form. I named it what the action is supposed to do... sorry for the confusion

Comment: Right, I should have seen that. So just add an instance of that to `Globals.ThisAddin.CustomTaskPanes`

Comment: It still doesn't show up when I start the add-in, :/

Comment: Alright thanks to your help I got it to work I just needed to set the Visibility to true

Comment: Maybe it's `Visible` property is false by default? I don't have the means to run my code right now (hence comments only) but I add the custom task pane in the Ribbon_Load event then set `Visible` to false which implies the default is true but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with thanks to @Crowcoder. Remember to set your Visibility to true...

```
namespace WordAddIn2
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        SidePane sP;
        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            sP = new SidePane();
            myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(sP, "Title");
            myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```